# CloseableHttpClient session not closed

Tags: java, httpclient

I create a CloseableHttpClient with intent to connect to our Tomcat to execute some services.
After the request i call close on the client but I still see that there a active Session in Tomcat.
Should not close invalidate the session?

```
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
    .setSocketTimeout(1000 * 60 * 2)
    .setConnectTimeout(4000)
    .build();
HttpClientBuilder cl = HttpClients.custom();
cl.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig);
cl.setSSLSocketFactory(makeSSLConnectionSocketFactory());


HttpGet postMethod = new HttpGet(url);
try (CloseableHttpClient client = cl.build();
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(postMethod);) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: It is probably the first Closeable you didn't wrap in a try-with-resources: CloseableHttpClient client = cl.build();

Comment: Sorry it was a typo

Comment: What do you mean with sesion, a `HttpSession`? Unless you invalidate that, the ssession lives until the session is timed out (default 30 minutes).

Comment: Well yes, a HttpSession. Should it not be invalidated with client.close() ?

Comment: Tomcat session management has nothing to do with your client call. When you submit a request a JSESSIONID cookie is returned via Set-Cookie:.  The same session ID now contains session data on the server and will be used when you submit JSESSIONID cookie via Cookie: directive in request.  This is how session is persisted, closed connection does nothing to the server-side session.  You need code on the server to invalidate if that is what you need.